# Typescript file updates not showing changes on the website

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

i am practicing using an existing Cloud application builds on Asp.net MVC , Angularjs v1x and gulp

The problem I am having , when I am editing my typescript file , it is converting into a js file after rebuilding the application, publishing the typescript, and js file but changes are not visible on the site.

i am using app.ts including controllers from different function from app.controller.ts file.
My question is what i am missing in the whole process of change and publishing typescript , js files . node, gulp configured in my working machine fine

please help me to resolve the issue
application running on cloud environment[image]